# Calculate sum of props from TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to calculate the sum of the props I'm passing to my child component but it seems to only work when I add them in the correct order. Ex. I enter math as 100, science as 100, and so on down the line, it will add correctly. But if I enter math as 100 then art as 100, totalscore will show as 100100 and not 200.

For example:

```
    var totalScore =
      this.props.math +
      this.props.science +
      this.props.history +
      this.props.gym +
      this.props.lunch +
      this.props.art

    if (e == 1 || e == 2 || e == 3) {
      if (isNaN(totalScore)) {
        return totalScore = 'fail';
      } else {
        return totalScore
      }
    }
```

How can I add a value these props in any order with the correct sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with the order and the order is NOT important. The problem is string concatenation. You are passing string instead of numbers

Explicity typecasting them like below should fix the issue

```
var totalScore =
      Number(this.props.math) +
      Number(this.props.science) +
      Number(this.props.history) +
      Number(this.props.gym) +
      Number(this.props.lunch) +
      Number(this.props.art)

    if (e == 1 || e == 2 || e == 3) {
      if (isNaN(totalScore)) {
        return totalScore = 'fail';
      } else {
        return totalScore
      }
    }
```

For reference, to pass the props as numbers, do this

```
<Component someProp={100} >
```

if you say `someProp="100"` it will be a string

Answer (score 2):

it seems like the props is a  string because the number you enter are concatenated. You can use the parseInt or parseFloat functions, or simply use the unary + operator:

example

```
 var totalScore =
      parseInt(this.props.math) +
      parseInt(this.props.science) 

Or 
   +this.props.science + 
   +this.props.math

Or
 parseFloat(this.props.math) +
parseFloat (this.props.science)
```

in short You need to convert the string to number